# How to restrict access to pages within laravel, when user hasn't accepted terms and conditions

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently designing a website that requires the user to agree to the terms and conditions before continuing and restricts them from accessing other pages through url if they haven't accepted the terms and conditions. What would be the best way of implementing this? I'm still fairly new to Laravel and haven't had much luck trying to implement it myself. I've looked into setting sessions which didn't work to well, and middleware wont work unless the user signs up before hand, which isn't what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `authorized` cookie to authenticate the visitor:

To store cookie on browser side:

```
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('authorized', 'true'));
```

To get the cookie value from request:

```
$authorized = $request->cookie('authorized');
```